# jquery variable selector issue

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

html:

```
<input id="input_1" type="text" value="some text"/>
<input id="input_2" type="text" value="some text"/>
```

js:

```
var input_1 = $('#input_1'),
input_2 = $('#input_2');
```

now I need to remove these value. So I removed value one by one.
  example:

```
  input_1.value('');
  input_2.value('');
```

but how can I remove these variables value in one line?
( ***without this method:  input_1.value('').end().input_2.value('');*** )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make use of `add` method.

```
input_1.add(input_2).val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input_1, #input_2").val('');
```

Comment: I want to use these variables not id.

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery `each()`(https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('input[id^='input_']').each(function( index ) {
     $(this).val(''); // reset each element value
});
```

**FYI**

`input[id^='input_']` selector selects all `input` elements with `id` attribute started with `'input_'` e.g input_1, input_2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to empty the value of multiple elements, then using class selector is an option for you.
Like that :

```
var input_vars = $(".elementClass");
input_vars.val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe via array?

```js
var clearMe = ['input1', 'input2'];

    for (i = 0; i < clearMe.length; i++) { 
        var thisClear = clearMe[i];
        
       $('#'+thisClear).val(''); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" name="test" value="testvalue1">  
<input type="text" id="input2" name="test" value="testvalue2">
<input type="text" id="input3" name="test" value="testvalue3">
```

The same with variables:

```js
var clear1 = $('#input1');
var clear2 = $('#input2');
var clearMe = [clear1, clear2];

    for (i = 0; i < clearMe.length; i++) { 
       clearMe[i].val(''); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" name="test" value="testvalue1">  
<input type="text" id="input2" name="test" value="testvalue2">
<input type="text" id="input3" name="test" value="testvalue3">
```

or.. simply:

```js
var clear = $('#input1, #input2');
clear.val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" name="test" value="testvalue1">  
<input type="text" id="input2" name="test" value="testvalue2">
<input type="text" id="input3" name="test" value="testvalue3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to both the textbox element and then use that class to clear the value.

$(".class").value("");

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Thanks everyone.

```
input_1.add(input_2).val("");
```